# xml_declaration = True <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: python, lxml

I am using this code:

```
tree.write(xmlFileOut, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

to write my xml with xml declaration but it is producing:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

But I need it to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I am using python with lxml.
What do I need to do?

Cheers.

Comment: They're the same thing.

Comment: If absolutely need it to produce the second one, although it is the same, is there anyway?

Comment: May we ask _why_ you _absolutely_ need to produce the second one?

Comment: A very awkward boss who knows nothing about xml. Would make my life easier if i could use " instead of '.

Comment: Anyone actually have the answer to this please, I know they are exactly the same, BUT, unfortunately I have to have to have the declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>